# Using AWS CloudWatch events to trigger a Lambda function that sends a response to a Lex bot

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I would like help with getting Lex to "initiate" a conversation on a set schedule, e.g. like when using cron() in CloudWatch. I know how to use a Cloudwatch event to trigger a Lambda function, but how can the response from Lambda get back to Lex?

The solution should preferably work for both Facebook Messenger and Twilio SMS.

I've looked into using API Gateway to set up a web hook to Lambda, but that wouldn't have the CloudWatch event. These responses should be sent when a value changes in a database, and CloudWatch seemed to be the solution to that. However, to do that, CloudWatch would have to be able to trigger a lambda that can send a response through Lex.

This is all giving me a headache and making me very tired. I have tried and tried to find a solution, so this is kind of my last resort. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used 3rd party integrations with Lex myself but taking a guess here... bypass lex and try to send directly to Facebook/Twilio API via Lambda using the same messaging platform access keys you have configured for Lex. (Act as if you are Lex!)

Include whatever Lex needs in terms of meta data (context..etc) with your message in case the user responds. I assume if the user responds, it will use the Lex callback URL.